# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined" when using ember's linkTo helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Using:

- ember.js commit b2e82ae
- ember-data.js commit 001ba0c
- handlebars-1.0.rc.2.js

This used to work already with the latest router API, but now breaks after upgrading to latest commit. This is also the first upgrade that tells me to use rc.2 for handlebars, that may be a hint.

The **linkTo** helper raises an error, when parsing the **todo_items** template: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined`.

```
# router
App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('todo_items', function() {
   this.route('todo_item', {
      path: '/:todo_item_id'
    });
  });
});

App.TodoItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.TodoItem.find();
  }
});

# todo_items.handlebars
<ul>
  {{#each item in content}}
  <li>
    {{#linkTo todo_items.todo_item item}}{{item.title}}{{/linkTo}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

It makes no difference when I wrap the first argument of linkTo in quotes: `linkTo "todo_items.todo_item" item`, the same error occurres.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by working from HEAD of ember.js. Switching to the official 1.0.0-pre.4 release solved it.

Comment: Thx Ginty, that works. I also [noticed](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/b2e82aecf22c2654eb6e6894f5a0b82e2adfe5ed) it looks like the linkTo is subject to WIP, so I better wait a few... hours before working from HEAD again.

Comment: I am working from official rc1 version and getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use precompiled templates ?

I use grunt-ember-templates for compiling handlebars template and I've the same bug

I've solved this problem with upgrading the handlebars version used for compiling templates.

Comment: Upgrade the handlebars version used for compiling templates solved the problem for me (I'm using the HEAD revision of Ember). Thanks ;)

Comment: I use ember as part of a Rails app with the ember-rails gem.

Comment: I think this commit resolve the problem https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/commit/b7d129798fe0905ec1fba633bf66bab1bd878510